# A' contains B-A?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Fill in the blank question: 
>    $A'\ \ \text{___}\ \ B-A$
>
> **Options**:
>
> 1) non comparable,
>
> 2)  $\subset$,
>
> 3) $\supset$.

Correct answer is option 3. But, I think answer is option 2 i.e. $A' \subset B-A$

Here, I took following test elements for sets $A$ and $B$.

$A = \{2,3,4\}, \quad B = \{1, 2, 3\}$

$U = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$

$A' = \{1\}$, and

$B-A = \{1\}$

So, I assume that  $A'\subset B-A$. But, answer is other way around. Why?

Comment: In regards to a good resource for LaTeX/MathJax symbols:  http://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm#M  It also has a link to a tool for drawing symbols that you don't know the name of and it will give you a list:  http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html  .  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following case, which expands on your example by adding 5 to $U$:

$A = \left\{2,3,4\right\}, B = \left\{1, 2, 3\right\}$

$U = \left\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\right\}$

$A' = \left\{1,5\right\}$ and

$B-A = \left\{1\right\}$

This shows that $A' \supset B-A$.

Obviously, this is not a proof, but hopefully provides some motivation as to the plausibility of the answer.  I hope this helps.